# Do all modern browsers work according to Mark-and-sweep algorithm?

Tags: javascript, browser, garbage-collection, mark-and-sweep

It's not entirely clear to me how garbage collector works for js.

Do all modern browsers work according to **Mark-and-sweep** algorithm (Chrome, Firefox ...)?

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Memory_Management#reference-counting_garbage_collection)

> Internet Explorer 6 and 7 are known to have reference-counting garbage collector for DOM objects. Cycles are a common mistake that can generate memory leaks.

It seems to me that only IE works according to reference-counting garbage collector. Is it true?

Comment: Well, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56218239/which-modern-browsers-use-mark-and-sweep-algorithm-for-garbage-collection) seems to be really relevant here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which modern browsers use Mark and Sweep Algorithm for Garbage Collection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56218239/which-modern-browsers-use-mark-and-sweep-algorithm-for-garbage-collection)

Comment: So, I see that I was right